# Minimal kafka-spark consumer

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I have been looking for a minimal `kafka`-`spark` consumer example in scala and did not find one with the 'New Consumer Configs' (http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#newconsumerconfigs) - rather the old ones. 
I have been looking through many sites and did not find an example featuring the required configuration settings.

Would someone have such an example please?